# How to print vector-values in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV.
Please tell me how to print these objects using `std::cout`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;  
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, one way to do it would be:

```
for (auto vec : contours)
    for (auto v : vec)
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

and then for hierarchy:

```
for (auto vec : hierarchy)
    std::cout << vec << std::endl;
```

The key point is that the OpenCV data structures overload the `<<` operator, so you can use them directly with `cout`.